# What do you chemists need from a periodic table?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-table

I am developing a website and later on an app with the periodic table. The reason I started was that I thought almost all the other periodic tables was awfully ugly. 
I do not only want to make it a well-looking periodic table, but I want to make it easy and smart to use combined with the design.

**My question to you:**
Which features do you require and want from an online periodic table?
I am also asking for the smallest features you can come up with. The more the better!

---

Features I already have got:

- The periodic table view with number, symbol, name, and type of element (like noble gas)
- Detailed information on an element on a specific page for each element including:

  - Number, name, and symbol
  - Discovery, etymology, and meaning
  - Electron configuration
  - Electronegativity
  - Density
  - Melting and boiling point
  - Phase at room temperature

I hope you chemists can help me. By the way, the service will be free of charge to use when it is developed.

Right now it looks like this:
[image: The Periodic table]

and when you click on one of the elements:
[image: Detailed description of Oxygen]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68611/discussion-on-question-by-rasmus-lauridsen-what-do-you-chemists-need-from-a-peri).

Comment: Look on wikipedia. Every information their infobox on elements give is supposedly relevant.

Comment: @Karl Do you think all the information should be included?

Comment: Why make your app unuseful for half the people? If I can't find everything, I would'nt use it at all, but stick to wikipedia.

Comment: I’m going to vote to close as primarily opinion based. Reason: I don’t need the periodic table for anything; I know where each element is, I know the atomic masses of the most common ones and if I am missing a mass I look it up on Wikipedia. However, others will most certainly disagree; therefore every chemist will use the periodic table for something different.

Comment: Well. Before you do that. Could you do me the favor of telling me what people like you who for the most doesn't need a periodic table require when you are using one?

Comment: @Karl thank you. I will include all the information I can find!